# Reading multiple inputs from a .txt file

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, text-processing, grep

I want to use the list of phone numbers(many) in a file "input_loan_msisdn.txt" as input to my script (the phone numbers in the file are listed line by line), and use it as a keyword to grep my output from another file yemmy_snap*

A sample input file:

```
2348093700000 
2348180000000 
2348090000000 
2348097000000
2347050000000 
2348090000000 
2348170000000
```

See my attempt below:

```
#!/bin/bash

for msisdn in $(cat input_loan_msisdn.txt); do
    cd /onip/cdr/output/snapshot/yemmy/backup
    zgrep $msisdn yemmy_snap* | \
    awk -F "|" '{print $1 "   " $14 "   " $4 }' ocs_snapshot*.unl \
         > /onip/app/cbpapp/RETURN_LOAN/output_loan_msisdn.txt;
done
```

Comment: What does not work? What is the output you expected from `zgrep $msisdn yemmy_snap* | awk -F "|" '{print $1 "   " $14 "   " $4 }'`?

Comment: Also, it would be nice to have a few sample of your input file (redacted if necessary) to see how it's formatted.

Comment: I am not getting any output, so I guess its that part.

Comment: Input is a list of numbers in the format: 2348093700000
2348180000000
2348090000000
2348097000000
2347050000000
2348090000000
2348170000000

Comment: the numbers are on separate lines though

Comment: Is `yemmy_snap*` a single file happening to end with a star '*' or a pattern ("all files starting with yemmy_snap")? How is it formatted? It's hard to tell if your `awk` command is correct without this information.

Comment: yemmy, you should [EDIT](http://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/161886) your own post to provide updates to the question. Comments lose some formatting, as you've seen.

Comment: @Jeff Schaller: Thanks, will keep that in mind

Comment: the summary is that there are two file input_loan_msisdn.txt and yemmy_snap* and I want to grep the list of numbers inside input_loan_msisdn.txt line-by-line inside file yemmy_snap*

Comment: @yemmy don't summarise here in the comments. Put this in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `while` loop is needless, since `grep` has the `-f` switch:

```
 grep -f input_loan_msisdn.txt yemmy_snap* | <do other stuff with the data>
```

Note that if the file passed to `-f` has *any* blank lines it it, `grep` matches *every* line, (it acts like `cat`).  Supposing the file passed to `-f` cannot be edited in advance, it can be fixed at runtime like so:

```
grep '.' input_loan_msisdn.txt | \
grep -f - yemmy_snap* | <do other stuff with the data>
```

From `man grep`:

```
-f FILE, --file=FILE
      Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  If this option is used
      multiple times or is combined with  the  -e  (--regexp)  option,
      search  for  all  patterns  given.  The empty file contains zero
      patterns, and therefore matches nothing.
```

Comment: the summary is that there are two file input_loan_msisdn.txt and yemmy_snap* and I want to grep the list of numbers inside input_loan_msisdn.txt line-by-line inside file yemmy_snap*

Comment: @yemmy, it's unclear from your comment as to whether or not you've you tried the above `grep -f` answer.  Please elaborate.

Comment: I have tried it but it just make a copy of the whole file. i.e it doesn't limit the output to just the list of numbers in the files but spools all.

Comment: @yemmy, that it spools them all implies there's a blank line in `input_loan_msisdn.txt`.   See revised answer (where it says "Note...") for remedy.